# C# add items to ImageListBoxControl

Tags: c#, image, imagelist

I have some troubles adding items(string with image) to ImageListBoxControl.
Image I get from resources;
I already added image to ImageList, but i don't know how to add it to ImageListBoxControl, because it requires imageIndex but i don't know how to get it;
Can someone help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

The index is the position where the item is (starts from 0), so let's say if it's the 3rd item in the list, the index is 2 (index is an int btw, not a string).

To add it to your ImageListBoxControl you have to do this if I'm right:

```
System.Drawing.Image myImage = "Image location";
ImageListBoxControl.Images.Add(myImage);
```

NOTE: I've never used this control before.